# JQuery Fancy Box Text Overflow

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, scrollbar, overflow

So here's a working example of my situation: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/71/)

The pic is just the first thing I grabbed of google images. But anyway, when you click on the pictuure, it shows that picture again but with the caption text on top of it. That **IS** what I want, but what I don't want is that overflow. Is there anyway to bound that text within the picture window and put a scroll bar on it?

If so, can I even put a custom scrollbar on it using a jquery plugin called uscrollbar. To use it you just have to do:

```
$("#div").uscrollbar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any additional plugins for correcting this.

Specifying/Overriding the following styles to the `.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title` CSS class will solve it.

```
.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {

    /* new */
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;

    visibility: visible;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vkDcG/73/

Comment: okay i guess my follow-up question is, HOW to I apply the custom scrollbar?

Comment: ahh.. ok. Now *that* may need a plugin. :-)

Comment: Yah, i have the plugin, it's uscrollbar. I use it on other parts of my website. But I'm wondering how to apply it to this text window. Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest attaching it using `$("#div").uscrollbar();` on the `beforeLoad` or `onLoad` event event (if fancybox has one such event). Let me check.

Comment: yeah if you see in my fiddle code, I use the onload event. But i have no idea WHAT to attach the scrollbar to.

Comment: I think you should be able to do `$('.fancybox-inner').uscrollbar();` but be sure to call it *after* the fancybox DOM is generated fully. i.e. inside `onComplete`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17407/discussion-between-john-bernal-and-techfoobar)

Comment: With this solution, you only see the text (title/caption) but not the image, which supposedly is the intended target in fancybox.